# Proper syntax for breaking up multiple parameters in a method

Tags: java, android

I come from an iOS background and am looking to replicate an iOS app in Android.

One of my methods in iOS has a method of

`-(void) updateLabelWithText:(NSString*)newText withTag:(int)theTag;`

I am trying to replicate my app as closely as possible in Android. But I can't seem to find any documentation on how to create a method similar to

`public void updateLabelWithText(String newText) withTag(int)theTag;`

The closest I can get is

`public void updateLabelToText(String newText, int theTag);`

Does Java support method creation in this manor?

Comment: No.  The only language that does something like that is ObjectiveC.  That's one of the reason many developers really hate ObjectiveC-  instead of using the standard syntax that almost every language for the past 50 years uses, it did something that's harder to read and harder to use because Steve Jobs like it better.  Get used to standard function call syntax, absolutely nothing in the world but iOS uses the other stuff.

Comment: Also, replicating one platform as closely as possible on another is generally not a good idea.  Its one thing to replicate the functionality, or even the UI.  Replicating the code like that will lead to lots of bugs, performance issues, and difficulty to maintain/write.  Platforms are different, some thing will be easier, some harder, many just different.  Write code that works well for that platform, don't do something just because its the same way you did it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: If you're asking whether or not you can split your parameters similarly to how it's done with Objective C then the answer is no. That's simply not how it's done in Java. The syntax is different.

*Previous answer:*

Yes, pretty much any programming language does. Where going from Objective-C to Java might be a bit confusing for you is that you don't need to declare the method more than once. In Objective-C you declare your method in your header file, and define the method in your source file. You don't do this in Java. In Java it's all done in one file.

So you want something like this in your class:

```
public void updateLabelToText(String newText, int theTag)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: @TimCastelijns I guess I'm confused as to what he's asking then. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yeah obj-c has this weird syntax for defining and calling methods

Comment: @TimCastelijns Oh, I know. I can't imagine what it would be like to learn that as your first language. That's just... unfortunate.